# How to emulate a Google local search query?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, search-results, local-seo

There must be a way, since services such as [RankTrackr.com](http://ranktrackr.com) and [WhiteSpark](http://www.whitespark.ca) can get pretty accurate results?

Is there some sort of parameters I can add to the URL to emulate a local search for a particular city in the United States?

Comment: This is a tad-bit off-topic here, but for google, what you may want to try is put in the country code as the domain extension instead of .com. For example, replace google.com with google.co.uk. It will give you real results but it may be tailored to the country.

Comment: When you say "local" are you asking about "country" local, or "city" local?  Please edit your question to provide additional information.

Comment: Keep in mind that automating queries against Google is against their terms of service: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en   If you do this, your IP address will start having to answer CAPTCHAs to search on Google.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have specified that I am emulating a local search for a particular city in the United States. By "automated", do you mean with code? Or, just manually altering the URL string?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you run queries through IP addresses for the localities you're interested in. Many of the larger proxy services allow you to choose from multiple metropolitan areas in most developed countries.

Obviously, companies doing this at scale (i.e. commercial rank trackers) have to source vast numbers of IP addresses and use them carefully to maintain a light footprint because, as pointed out in comments on your question, it's against Google's ToS.